# how to make a sidemenu using yii1.1

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii 1.1.I  have successfully installed the bootstrap extension from https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap.

I want to make a side menu for my admin panel. I couldn't find any documentation. please help me. I am new to Yii

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'page-sidebar-menu sidenav hidden-phone hidden-tablet' //You can customize this for your application
                )
            ),
        )); ?>
```

Comment: Please refer. Use Layout main.php file and call bootstrap div class as mention below
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu


<div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse side-menu">
    <?php
     echo "Call Yii1 menu" // You can create your own menu widget
    ]);
    ?>
</div>

Comment: can you please give a working example..

Comment: @dipti thanks for your reply. can you please give a code snippet

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/sidebar#installation
Please refer attached provided example.  Download sidebar zip and try. Refer example
I am using yii2 and many widget of kartik which using in yii2